# From windows-1251 to UTF-8 Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, encoding

I use gem "Nokogiri" on Rails 3.2.13. When I pars site, I get site from with coding windows-1251, but I need UTF-8 for my work. How can I do it? Help me, please.

PS

```
require 'iconv'
ic = Iconv.new('UTF-8','Windows-1251')
@convertedstr = ic.iconv(@output.to_s)
```

This code doesnt work but I don`t know why.

PPS Sorry, but I`m beginner in RoR.

Comment: what version of Ruby?

Comment: Version of Ruby is 1.9.3

Answer (score 8):

try

```
@output.force_encoding("cp1251").encode("utf-8", undef: :replace)
```

Comment: Thanks, it changed coding. But I have new problem.

`@page = Nokogiri::HTML(open('http://example.com'))`

@ouput has content from this page, contenet has russian symbols, and after encoding I see different symbols, but I need russian symbols.
As I know, Nokogiri have strings as UTF-8 internally. What should I do?